# How can I get sessionId from a request?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express

I use express to support my session management:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session({secret: 'mysecretcode'}));
```

I what to extract and save the sessionId from the request. However, the id I get from req.sessionID is different to that sent in the cookie:

```
req.sessionID --> 'E7oSoKmQfcMKnk5_jA5tF5vR'
cookie.connect.sid --> 's%3AE7oSoKmQfcMKnk5_jA5tF5vR.DQnYdDDcFn8K2JJHMgWL5DTzNYYwIU3DA5a10WImA7U';
```

1. Why these two are different?
2. How can I get connect.sid before sending a response?

Comment: Use req.sessionID, which is setup by Express in the middleware call you have in your code (which I assume comes above your route setup, if any). Note that the built-in MemoryStore that Express provides for sessions is not recommended for "production" use (no GC, etc), if you have any plans to create and store session data beyond sessionID.

Answer (score 3):

I read the sourcecode of connect.session, and got:

```
key = options.key || 'connect.sid'
```

and

```
var val = 's:' + signature.sign(req.sessionID, secret);
val = cookie.serialize(key, val);
debug('set-cookie %s', val);
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', val);
```

so, connect will set cookie into response header when response's 'header' event fired, and when you call response.end(), connect will save session data into store.

That's it.